# Checks which AD Groups are empty

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

Hi guys so i am trying to pull Empty AD groups, it does pull some AD groups but it also pulls groups that do have members, like Domain Users and Domain Computers. This is the script i have

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Members | where {-not $_.members}
```

The script is suppose to return only empty AD groups.

Comment: So you want to find groups with no members but excluding well known groups basically ? your question is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

First, as you have it, your query is getting every group on your domain, then the filtering is done on your computer. It would run a lot quicker if you put the filter in `Get-ADGroup`, like this:

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(!member=*)"
```

(I like to use `-LDAPFilter` rather than `-Filter` since it has to translate whatever you put in `-Filter` into an proper LDAP query anyway. I like having control over the exact query that gets sent.)

Second, the reason those groups are being returned is because they're being used as a primary group. A user (or computer) is not stored in the `member` attribute of its primary group. Instead, the `primaryGroupId` attribute of the user (or computer) is set to the `primaryGroupToken` of the group. Unfortunately, that makes it difficult to filter those groups out without doing a second search (for each group returned) checking if it is used as a primary group.

If your organization doesn't ever change the primary group, then it will always be `Domain Users` for users and `Domain Computers` for computers, and you can just exclude those groups from your results.

Comment: +1 for the ldap filter approach but this query can return many more groups than just Domain Users or Domain Computers. It can return any built-in group not having members. The way to go is to exclude by `groupType` or a predicate that checks if `.ObjectSid` is WellKnown

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That's one way to do it, however any group can be a primary group, not just built-in groups. It just depends on how accurate you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Getting empty groups has some surprising aspects.

One is that `Get-ADGroup xxx -Properties Members` does not get the primary group membership members, as noted above.

Another is that `Get-ADGroupMember` will return a different number of members. But `Get-ADGroupMember` fails on groups larger than `5000`. You can perform `Get-ADGroupMember` for each group found by `Get-ADGroup`, to exclude large groups, but you still need to exclude the large primary groups that `Get-ADGroup` does not know e.g. Domain Users and Domain Computers, otherwise `Get-ADGroupMember` will give an error about size exceeded.

You can exclude some of the default domain groups with `-not $_.IsCriticalSystemObject`, but this does not catch some default groups that are not critical system objects, like DHCP Administrators.